# Display and Style a Selected Value From an Array

Tags: php

I am trying to style what is selected from my array, however when I run my code I get a syntax error and it has to do with my h1 styling I believe. Im trying to Echo a h1 that displays the color name and uses the color name to style the color of the h1 using inline styling to set the color.

```
<body>
    <form id = '' name = '' action='php 07 array 01.php' method='post' class = ''>
        <select id = 'colorNumber' name = 'colorNumber'>

            <option value = '0'>0</option>
            <option value = '1'>1</option>
            <option value = '2'>2</option>
            <option value = '3'>3</option>
            <option value = '4'>4</option>
            <option value = '5'>5</option>
            <option value = '6'>6</option>
            <option value = '7'>7</option>
            <option value = '8'>8</option>
            <option value = '9'>9</option>
        </select>
        <input type = 'submit' value = 'GO' class = '' id = 'go'>
    </form>
</body>

<?php

$colorArray = array("sepia", "gold", "carrot", "orange", "yellow", "blue", "pink", "purple", "black", "warmgrey");

$colorEfx = $_POST['colorNumber'];

$differentColor = $colorArray[$colorEfx];

echo <h1 style = 'color:$differentColor; '>$differentColor</h1>;

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your echo statement is wrong, it should be surrounded by `""`:

`echo "<h1 style = 'color:$differentColor; '>$differentColor</h1>;"`

Answer (score 1):

Did you see which line the error is?

Try this:

```
echo "<h1 style=\"color:$differentColor\">$differentColor</h1>";
```